# Join with Category Table

Tags: magento2, catalog, product-collection, category-products, category-listing

I need to show all Subcategories and their products on category view page as

```
-- CategoryName 1 <br />
-- -- Product List for category1

--- Category Name 2 <br />
--- Product List for category2
```

The number of products is less hence we don't need toolbar as well as filters.

How can I join category table with `ProductCollection` so that I can get category name and it's URL on list page? I want the product collection to be sorted by category Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can have subcategories in product list page and then for each subcategory you can call product collection and render.
Change the catalog_category_view layout and call you custom block and template with subcategories and product collection for each subcategory.